# Logstash filter for ip

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Need logstash filter for client ip , 12.34.56.78:1234

I need to filter the client Ip , only I require 12.34.56.78 not the things after :.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**GROK pattern:**

```
%{IP:ip}:%{GREEDYDATA:others}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{
  "ip": [
    [
      "12.34.56.78"
    ]
  ],
  "IPV6": [
    [
      null
    ]
  ],
  "IPV4": [
    [
      "12.34.56.78"
    ]
  ],
  "others": [
    [
      "1234"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (I haven't tested it):

```
mutate {
  gsub => ["ip_field_name", ":\d+", ""]
}
```

The `:\d+` will capture the `:` and all following digits and the mutate#gsub option will replace this with an empty string.